# TCP-Server sending a file in a packet structure (to a non Java client)

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

Me asking one of those questions again :P
Since I'm porting my C++ server to a Java server (and it's nearly done) I'm missing only one thing:
Sending files.
I can't wrap my head around on how to construct the packet in Java to send it via DataOutputStream.
In C++ I prepared the packet in this way (first 4bytes reserved for the file_size, rest the file itself):

```
char *pData = new char[file_size];

memcpy(pData, charArray.data(), file_size);

char *packet = new char[file_size + 4];
memset(packet, 0, file_size + 4);

*(int*)(packet) = file_size;
memcpy((char*)(packet + 4), pData, file_size);

int r = file_size + 4;
sendall(stream, packet, &r);
```

I hope you can help me out here, I'm able to construct simple packets but this one is giving me a headache :P
Do I merge the bytes or how would I accomplish the C++ code in Java x..x
Thanks in advance!

sendall func:

```
int sendall(TCPStream *s, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;
    int bytesleft = *len;
    int n;

    while(total < *len)
    {
        n = s->send(buf+total, bytesleft);
        if (n == -1) break;
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total;

    return n ==-1 ? -1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? You send 4 bytes with the size then all the bytes of the file content. Are you asking how to send the 4-byte size with the right endianness? You're using `DataOutputStream`, which sends `int` values with high-byte first, so if that's what the C++ did, then call `writeInt(int v)` followed by `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)`. If C++ was sending low byte first, then why are you using `DataOutputStream`?

Comment: The question is how to pack it under 1 "packet" here I mean into one byte array, and send all that info then, and not sending length, then sending the file content as byte-array

Comment: Since you are porting you may not care about C++ notes, but, what's the point of copying from `charArray.data()` to `pData`? Looks like you could save a step and `memcpy((char*)(packet + 4), charArray.data(), file_size);` or save a lot of trouble and send `file_size` and then `charArray.data()` separately. TCP is a stream, so unless you have extra protocol header being added in `sendall` it doesn't matter what you decide is a packet. TCP's going to send your message in whatever sized/shaped blobs it wants.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, that also applies to java. What does `sendall` do? If it's just a thin wrapper for a standard socket write, you can reduce all of your work to one `DataOutputStream`, one call to `writeInt` and one call to `write`. Question cannot be answered without code for `sendall` or guesswork.

Comment: `int sendall(TCPStream *s, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;
    int bytesleft = *len;
    int n;

    while(total < *len)
    {
        n = s->send(buf+total, bytesleft);
        if (n == -1) break;
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total;

    return n ==-1 ? -1 : 0;
}`

well, damn the comment :P will add it in main post aswell

Comment: [Except for Endian.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) Watch out for endian when transmitting `file_size`. Java always speaks big endian unless you tell it to do otherwise. C++ speaks whatever's native to the hardware.

Comment: The C++ code could be reduced to `sendall(stream, (char*)&file_size, sizeof (file_size)); sendall(stream, charArray.data(), file_size);`. Again watch out for endian and make darn sure that `int` is 32 bit. [Better still use `uint32_t` from `<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java equivalent of that C code is:

```
int file_size = ...;
byte[] file_data = ...;

byte[] packet = new byte[file_size + 4];
ByteBuffer.wrap(packet).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(file_size);
System.arraycopy(file_data, 0, packet, 4, file_size);
```

You need to confirm whether the file size was sent with high or low byte first, and change to `BIG_ENDIAN` if needed.

Since C code just added file size as `int`, and was likely run on Intel processor, the result was `LITTLE_ENDIAN`, which is why I specified that in the code above. But as @paulsm4 [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935429/tcp-server-sending-a-file-in-a-packet-structure-to-a-non-java-client/48936078?noredirect=1#comment84879204_48936078), you should test this.

Comment: Regarding [byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness): sockets "network order" and Java byte order are both [Big-Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian).  Most hosts are Intel CPUs ([Little-Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian)).  The original C++ code is just "sending bytes" (no [htonX](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) or equivalent).  So although the above code *SHOULD* work ... I would definitely *TEST* it.  The original code should probably have used `htonl()` for "file_size"...

Comment: @paulsm4 You're right, most hosts are Intel and hence `LITTLE_ENDIAN`, and since C code just wrote the `int` value, I gonna change the answer to `LITTLE_ENDIAN` by default, so it'll likely work for OP is-as.

Comment: I'm aware of the byte order and the endiness problem and in my Java programm it was handled before sending. Though @Andreas code port did the thing at my side, I think I got now how that ByteBuffer is gonna work on these areas.

user4581301 I was doing it step by step, that's why the code looks like this^^

Thanks all you guys!